# Disable a specific app from ever bouncing in dock

Tags: dock, notifications

I want to stop Filezilla from ever bouncing in my dock.  It just keeps bouncing and bouncing and derails from my work.

Is it possible to stop one app from bouncing?

Comment: This would also be very useful to developers who like to write malware.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's all or nothing with the Dock. You have two options: disable bouncing for anything and everything by entering

```
defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool TRUE; killall Dock
```

into a Terminal window, or modify and recompile Filezilla, which is not something anyone would want to do I guess. (A third option would be to get a new FTP client. Honestly, Cyberduck is really good.)

Comment: I have been very close to that last option, but I'm hanging in for five more days to see.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that a few days after this I did switch to Cyberduck, which rules.

Comment: ForkLift is the one I use and love